# fetching details from jenkins workspace to build another step in the same jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins job that generates properties file in the workspace.
I want to know if it is possible read the property file from workspace and then pass it as a argument for a program in the next build step of the same job??

I tried reading to read the file via a groovy script
echo env.WORKSPACE
64
String fileContents = new File("${env.WORKSPACE}"/key_generate.properties").getText('UTF-8')

but i get the below error
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "groovy" (in C:\xyz\directory path)

I am using a **windows** node

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `java.io.File` because it is prohibited for security reasons, for example. Instead you can use Jenkins step [`readFile`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace) to read a file from workspace. Try this in your code:

```
String fileContents = readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/key_generate.properties"
```